# IntegrityError: The row in table 'main_post' with primary key '2' has an invalid foreign key: main_post.author_id cointains a value '1'

Tags: python, django, web

After makemigrations, then migrate I got this error

IntegrityError: The row in table 'main_post' with primary key '2' has an invalid foreign key: main_post.author_id cointains a value '1' that does not have a corresponding value in auth_user.id

I try some solutions in similar question but it doesnot work

My models.py

```
User = get_user_model()


class PostView(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.user.username

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    overview = models.TextField()
    detail = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = RichTextUploadingField(config_name='post_ckeditor')
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    featured = models.BooleanField()
    previous_post = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='previous', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank = True, null = True)
    next_post = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='next', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank = True, null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={
            'id': self.id
            })
    
    def get_update_url(self):
        return reverse('post-update', kwargs={
            'id': self.id
            })
    
    def get_delete_url(self):
        return reverse('post-delete', kwargs={
            'id': self.id
            })

    @property
    def get_comments(self):
        return self.comments.all().order_by('-timestamp')

    @property
    def view_count(self):
        return PostView.objects.filter(post=self).count()
    
    @property
    def comment_count(self):
        return Comment.objects.filter(post=self).count()
```

My views.py

```
#Some code not include in this

def post(request, id):
    most_recent = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:3]
    category_count = get_category_count()
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    PostView.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, post=post)
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.instance.post = post
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('post-detail', kwargs={
                'id':post.id
                }))
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'post': post,
        'category_count':get_category_count,
        'most_recent': most_recent,
    }
    return render(request, 'post.html', context)
```

Comment: Where is `main_post`'s code?

Comment: Do you understand what the error message means?

Comment: :(( no...:(... i don't get the error message, i try to figure it out but I dont get it

Comment: @Mel: In my models.py

Comment: It seems like you have somehow created a post (with ID/primary key 2) without there being a user/author created yet. Alternatively, there was a user before, but somehow it was removed. You must have (unless I'm missing something) done some additional steps after running `makemigrations` and `migrate`. It's hard to tell where things went wrong atm, it would help if you could describe what you did after migration. You probably want to use the [`login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) decorator for the `post` view.

Comment: If you want to reset your database, you can simply delete the project's `db.sqlite3` file and remove all files in your app's `migrations` folder, __except__  the `__init__.py` file (this must remain, otherwise your migrations won't work). Then you can rerun the migrations and see if the error persists or not. This assumes that you are using sqlite3 for your database.